# Youtube API Handling Deleted video error

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api

I have written code to get playlist and the video lists within them in different text files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""

YouTube Playlist Extrator.
A tool to extract playlists from YouTube API which in todays YouTube page format is very difficult to extract.
It also extracts video lists per playlist and hence takes bit longer to run for long playlists.

"""


#from profiler import Profiler
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
import os

try:
    import urllib.request as urlLibReq
    PY3 = True
except:
    import urllib as urlLibReq
    PY3 = False

def getInput():
    if PY3:
        return input("Enter username of YouTube channel: ")
    elif not PY3:
        return raw_input("Enter username of YouTube channel: ")

def xmlParser(url):
  page = urlLibReq.urlopen(url)
  text = page.read().decode("utf8")
  return parseString(text)

def extractplaylist(userId):
    url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+ userId +"/playlists?v=2"
    dom = xmlParser(url)
    total = int(dom.getElementsByTagName("openSearch:totalResults")[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
    startIndex, listEntry = 1 , []
    while startIndex <= total:
        url_new = url + "&max-results=50&start-index="+ str(startIndex)
        dom = xmlParser(url_new)
        entry = dom.getElementsByTagName("entry")
        for node in entry:
            id_data = node.getElementsByTagName("id")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
            id_split = id_data.split(':')
            playlist_id = id_split[5]
            playlist_title = node.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
            extractvideolist(userId, playlist_id, playlist_title)
            listEntry.append(str(playlist_title))
            startIndex += 1
    listEntry.sort()
    writer = open(userId+"_playlist.txt","w")
    writer.write("\r\n".join(map(str, listEntry)))
    writer.close()

def extractvideolist(userId, playlist_id, playlist_title):
    url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/"+ playlist_id +"?v=2"
    dom = xmlParser(url)
    total = int(dom.getElementsByTagName("openSearch:totalResults")[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
    startIndex, listEntry = 1 , []
    while startIndex <= total:
        url_new = url + "&max-results=50&start-index="+ str(startIndex)
        dom = xmlParser(url_new)
        entry = dom.getElementsByTagName("entry")
        for node in entry:
            video_title = node.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
            listEntry.append(str(video_title))
            startIndex += 1
    playlist_title = playlist_title.replace("'","\'")
    writer = open(playlist_title+"_videolist.txt","w")
    writer.write("\r\n".join(map(str, listEntry)))
    writer.close()
    print("written", playlist_title)
    try: os.mkdir(userId)
    except: pass
    os.system('mv "'+ playlist_title +'_videolist.txt" '+ userId)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = getInput()
    extractplaylist(name)
    #Profiler.report()
```

The code fails when there is a deleted video in the playlist. How do I deal with such a thing?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a use case of this failing, which line in your code fails, and/or the error you are seeing.

Comment: I mainly need data from the user ['nptelhrd'][1]. The playlist  playlist Chemical - Mass Transfer Operations I has a Deleted Video and hence failing in line 66 to 69.

  [1]youtube.com/user/nptelhrd

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an else clause to your for loop to break out of the while loop when the for loop ends.

```
while startIndex <= total:
    url_new = url + "&max-results=50&start-index="+ str(startIndex)
    dom = xmlParser(url_new)
    entry = dom.getElementsByTagName("entry")
    for node in entry:
        id_data = node.getElementsByTagName("id")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
        id_split = id_data.split(':')
        playlist_id = id_split[5]
        playlist_title = node.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
        extractvideolist(userId, playlist_id, playlist_title)
        listEntry.append(str(playlist_title))
        startIndex += 1
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Sometimes these basic things do not strike at the coding instant.
Thanks